# delete indexedDB record with a webworker, in a Chrome App

Tags: google-chrome-app, indexeddb, web-worker

I can't seem to delete an indexedDB record from a webworker in a packaged Chrome App.  Everything works perfectly as a web application, but once it's packaged by Chrome, it doesn't delete.

The webworker IS being called, as it's sending the data to an api, but then fails to delete the record despite returning true!

Can anyone help?

Comment: How are you deleting it ? Show your code.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.  I was using another package (angular-charts) which didn't comply with the ng-csp issue, thus the application broke down. Stupid issue to have!